# ¿Cómo imprimo la matriz completa? c++

Tags: c++

Cuando Imprimo eso, solo me aparece el primer carácter que le correspondería al primer "1". Sin embargo lo que yo quiero es que se imprima todos los "1" de la matriz.

```
    void ubica(int x, int y) {
    Console::SetCursorPosition(x, y);
}

int main()
{


    int matriz[4][4]{
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
    };

    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            ubica(10, 10);
            if (matriz[f][c] == 1) {
                cout << char(254);
            }
        }
    }


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No es que te imprima sólo el primer `1`, es que te imprime todos los `1` en la posición `10`, `10`:

```
for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        ubica(10, 10); // <--- Todos a la 10,10
        if (matriz[f][c] == 1) {
            cout << char(254);
        }
    }
}
```

Cambia el código:

```
for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        ubica(10 + f, 10 + c); // <--- Todos a partir de la 10,10
        if (matriz[f][c] == 1) {
            cout << char(254);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir la matriz sólo debes recorrer por fila y columna e ir mostrando los valores en dichas posiciones:

```
for(int x=0;x<3;x++)  
    {
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++)  
        {
            cout<<matrix[x][y];  
        }
    cout<<endl;  
    }
```

Ahora, para mostar sólo los 1 que tienes:

```
for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            ubica(10, 10);
            if (matriz[f][c] == 1) {
                cout << matriz[f][c];
                // o sólo imprimir 1 ya que hiciste el chequeo del valor del elemento

            }
        }
    }
```